# Displaying time elapsed since epoch

Tags: java, time, calendar, epoch

I am working on creating a time app that calculates both the current time and the time elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970, in milliseconds. I went ahead and used Calendar and was able to successfully return the current time but for some reason the elapsed time returns 0. Not sure why that would be.

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Time time1 = new Time();
     System.out.println("Hour: " + time1.getHour() + " Minute: " +
                   time1.getMinute() + " Second: " + time1.getSecond());

     Time time2 = new Time();
     System.out.println("Elapsed time since epoch: " + time2.getElapsedTime());
  }
}

final class Time {
  private int hour;
  private int minute;
  private int second;
  private long secondsSinceEpoch;

  public Time() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  }

  public Time(long elapsedTime) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(2016, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 9);
    secondsSinceEpoch = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
  }

@Override
   public String toString() {
     return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  }

  public int getHour() {
     return hour;
  }

  public int getMinute() {
     return minute;
  }

  public int getSecond() {
     return second;    
  }

  public long getElapsedTime() {
   return secondsSinceEpoch;
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Please, save yourself the hassle if possible, and use the `java.time` library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting `elapsedTime` for `time2`. I think you wanted

```
Time time2 = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

**And** as pointed out in the comments, you aren't using `elapsedTime` in your constructor. Something like

```
public Time(long elapsedTime) {
    secondsSinceEpoch = elapsedTime / 1000;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank You.

Comment: im pretty sure that `elapsedTime` never does anything and is useless?

Comment: @skeidsberget2365 `System.out.println("Elapsed time since epoch: " + time2.getElapsedTime());` uses it.

Comment: that is the method `getElapsedTime()` not the parameter `elapsedTime` that is passed to the `Time(long elapsedTime)` constructor. `elapsedTime` is never used by any method.

Comment: Just got off work and saw the comments. I see what you mean. Fixed it and it seems to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong constructor for `time2` since you called `Time()` and this version does not set `secondsSinceEpoch`. Try using your other constructor `Time(long elapsedTime)` with any long value and see if it works. 
Like this ..

`Time time2 = new Time(10000);`

Then re-write this constructor since you never use `elapsedTime` anyway, or delete it completely and re-write the first constructor to assign a value to `secondsSinceEpoch`.

```
public Time() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    secondsSinceEpoch = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
  }
```